# PHP mysqli insert together with commas instead of one by one

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want here to achieve is to insert all the information in a row separated with commas and not making another column for each data.

I want this

```
john,mark,mary,luke,james
```

not this

```
john
mark
mary
luke
james
```

My code

```
// Get all the users
$query = "SELECT SAL.mentor AS mentor, ACC.username AS username ";
$query .= "FROM ec_accounts ACC ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN ec_info INF ON ACC.user_id = INF.iuid ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN ec_sales SAL ON ACC.user_id = SAL.suid ";
$query .= "ORDER BY SAL.mentor";

$s = $sqlConnection->query($query);

if (!$s) {
    die($sqlConnection->error);
} else {
    while ($row = $s->fetch_assoc()) {
        $exarr = explode(',', $row['username']);

        $sqlConnection->query("INSERT INTO mytable (exceptions) VALUES('$exarr')");
    }
}
```

Comment: so why do you use explode? :) and why you need do it in PHP. It looks like it can be done in database directly, anyway does not look like looping is neccesary

Comment: what is the value of `print_r($row);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write you insert query outside the while loop and concatenate you username with `,`

```
while ($row = $s->fetch_assoc()) {
    $username .= $row['username'] . ",";// create string like john,mark,mary,luke,james,

}
// outside while loop
$username = rtrim($username, ",");// remove last comma

$sqlConnection->query("INSERT INTO mytable (exceptions) VALUES('$username')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$s = $sqlConnection->query($query);
if (!$s) {
    die($sqlConnection->error);
} 
else {
    $str = '';
    while ($row = $s->fetch_assoc()) {
    // concat comma with $str when $str is not empty. so it concate comma from second circle
    if($str !=''){ $str .= ',';}
    //concat username one by one to make complete string
    $str .= $row['username']; 
}
// Finally do insert the complete string into a table
$sqlConnection->query("INSERT INTO mytable (exceptions) VALUES('$str')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use sql group_concat function in mysql

```
$query = "SELECT SAL.mentor AS mentor, group_concat(ACC.username) AS username";
$query .= "FROM ec_accounts ACC ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN ec_info INF ON ACC.user_id = INF.iuid ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN ec_sales SAL ON ACC.user_id = SAL.suid ";
$query .= "GROUP BY  mentor ";
$query .= "ORDER BY SAL.mentor";
```